# Error in FQLQuery

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have an [FQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Query_Language) query:

```
$FQLQuery = 'SELECT uid, sex, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in (implode(",", $man);)';
```

$man is an array.

This query is not working, and I am getting an error from Facebook saying "unexpected $ in line 45"

What's wrong with this query?

I tried it with `join()` also giving me the same error. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `$man` is a single dimensional array of Facebook User IDs, it should be:

```
$FQLQuery = 'SELECT uid, sex, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in ('.implode(",", $man).')';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the error, just change that line in your code like

```
$FQLQuery = "SELECT uid, sex, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in (implode(',', {$man}))";
```

and it will fix the error. As your $FQLQuery was surrounded by single quote, so $man was not being parsed a variable :)

Comment: "echo $FQLQuery" = 'SELECT uid, sex, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in (implode(",", $man);)';
should i make it like this?

Comment: nope, like this - 
echo "SELECT uid, sex, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in (implode(",", {$man});)";

Comment: I've posted the solution in my edited answer above. It happened because of the single quote in your code :)

Comment: it is giving me this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /home/xxx/public_html/xx/xx.php on line 157

Comment: Never mind, you dont need to echo as the error is already spotted out. It happened because of the single quotation. Copy the code from my answer above and run it. It will work.